# XCode - (iOS) Calling a local HTML file in to a SplitView via .plist reference?

Tags: xcode, ios, ipad, ios4, uiwebview

Newbie here (as may be evident by the question) but after many many hours of trying to figure this one out I have hit a point I need to ask for help...

Basically, all I want to do is parse a string from an array populated within a .plist. This string being a local URL. It works perfectly for external URL's, but no matter what I have tried for a local URL, all I get is nothing - Not even a URL not found (I lie - that did happen once but to never again be replicated).

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!

I have this code in DetailViewController:

```
    NSString *attractionURL = [detailItem description];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:attractionURL];
    [wikiView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

And this code in a popOver (RootViewController):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"recipes"
                        ofType:@"plist"];
    attractions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    self.title = @"Recipes";
```

With the URL's in a .plist file:

```
<array>
    <array>
        <string>Sirloin</string>
        <string>http://Resources/iPad/index.html</string>
    </array>
    <array>
        <string>Chasseur</string>
        <string>http://www.jamesmartinsfood.com</string>
    </array>

</array>
</plist>
```

Like I say, external URL works fine, local just doesn't do squat...

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your local URL isn't defined properly, it shouldn't have `http://` as it is not hosted on an http server.

It should be in a format like the following.

`file://localhost/var/mobile/Application/${APP_ID}/MyApp.app/index.html`

The first part is potentially ever changing based on device/environment and you will need to rely on the OS Framework to determine it, so in your plist you would only define the relative path to the local files and then prepend the path provided by the OS.

Something along the lines of

`NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:myFileName ofType:myFileExtension];`

Might work for you, where you `myFileName` is "index" and `myFileExtension` is "html"

Comment: Wangner
`NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:path];

NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

_leafWebView.delegate = self;

[_leafWebView loadRequest:request];`

using above code it fetch the www.google.com but dont load local page. if you can point out what I am missing. Thx in advance

Comment: @Alix I think you should post a new question for this.